# Applet + Html5 video tag

Tags: java, html, video, applet, video-streaming

I have the next issue
I have an html page which runs an applet method and then recovers the result of the applet (byte[]) and tries to put it in html5 video tag.
The task of the applet is to generate a video file (mp4) with some images.Then, it converts the file into byte[] and calls a javascript method to send the data:

```
File file = new File(path);



 FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);

        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        try {
            for (int readNum; (readNum = fis.read(buf)) != -1;) {
                bos.write(buf, 0, readNum); //no doubt here is 0
                //Writes len bytes from the specified byte array starting at offset off to this byte array output stream.

            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                    "EXCEPTION SEND FILE :" + ex.toString());

        }
        data = bos.toByteArray();
        JSObject win = JSObject.getWindow(this);
        win.call("readFile", new Object[]{data});
```

The code of the javascript method is the next one :

```
function readFile(file_data)
    {
      var video = document.getElementById('localVideoPreview');
      video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(file_data);
      video.play();
     }
```

But I have an error when I try to generate the URL from the file_data. It seems that file_data has not the correct type.
I don`t know what I'm doing wrong.
Any help?
Thanks in advance